# Finding the most common list in list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-lists, mode

I have a list of lists and I wish to find the most common list in every list and if there are multiple modes, than all of them. It sounds a bit complex so I will provide the example.

The list of lists that I have is:

```
My_List = [[], [[98, 362, 406, 719]], [], [], [[1118, 189, 1201, 338], [1118, 189, 1201, 338], [1118, 189, 1201, 338], [629, 86, 727, 209], [629, 86, 727, 209]], [], [[537, 18, 681, 202], [339, 177, 508, 372]]]
```

And the output that I want to have is:

```
New_List = [[], [[98, 362, 406, 719]], [], [], [[1118, 189, 1201, 338]], [], [[537, 18, 681, 202], [339, 177, 508, 372]]]
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Can you check you code, the first one `My_List ` raises an error and it seems that the second one `New_List ` does not match the specifications.

Comment: @hpchavaz hi, you are right My_List was not correct I am sorry about the mistake, I corrected it. But the New_List output seems right to me. Can you spesify the reason why you thought it was wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please show your efforts. What is keeping you from doing it?

Comment: @trincot Hello, the main problem is that when I use element wise mode selection functions like statistics.mode, statistic.multimode, collections.Counter etc. it gives me the error saying that I am putting in the wrong input as My_List is unhashable. 

I try to overcome this issue by using a for loop but then it gives me the error that says range is out of index. So, I kind of come to a stand still.

Comment: You can work around that error by converting the sublist into tuple, and then when you have done your processing, convert them back to list.

Comment: @trincot As I have never worked with tuples before I am not very keen on the subject. Should I try to convert my nested list only or all of the My_List?

Comment: Each of the inner lists, i.e. the ones that pose a problem (error) in your attempt.

Comment: @trincot I tried your suggestion but I could not manage with the multimode function. I will try further. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It will work with `Counter` and similar solutions, but then convert each inner list to a tuple, so it is hashable. Then get the most frequent result (with `Counter` you can use [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common)), and convert that result back to a list:

```
from collections import Counter

result = [
    [list(el) for el, freq in Counter(map(tuple, lst)).most_common(1)]
    for lst in My_List
]
```